# while UIAlertController is shown, parent's viewDidDisappear is not called (only on IOS8)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

sadly i had to migrate from UIActionSheet to UIAlertController because IOS8 removed the first's functionality.

before using that, every time i went to and from home screen, the parent's view "viewDidDisappear" was called so i could dismiss the menu i've created.

now it's not called anymore.
the code looks like:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController .... preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerSTyleActionSheet]
UIAlertAction* a = [....]
[alert addAction: a];
alert.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.myButton // the bar button from my view
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil] // maybe im not showing the view well?
```

i have no idea how to continue from here.. would love some help
Thanks.

== EDIT ==

i saw that it happens also with the deprecated UIActionSheet and also with UIDcoumentInteractionController - ONLY in IOS8, not in IO7

Comment: I have the same confusion. Maybe Apple Developer thinks it's transparent, so it's not really disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm thinking too simple here, but wouldn't it be the easiest to put whatever code you had in a separate method and call that method from viewDidDisappear and after that bit of code you use to present that alert controller?

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear {
    [self hideMenu];
}

- (void)hideMenu {
    // Do all stuff to hide the menu you previously did in viewDidDisappear
}
```

And alter that presenting code like this

```
// more code here
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
[self hideMenu];
```

Comment: but if i'll call the hideMenu right after displaying it wouldnt it just close the window right away?

also, shouldnt the viewDidDisappear be called when i'm moving to the home screen?

Comment: probably I am not understanding your real problem because your question is a bit incomple

Comment: Can i supply more information? as i understand, when going to home screen and coming back, the view should call "viewDidDisappear" and "viewDidAppear".
If a UIAlertController is shown (in the code above), i go back to home screen, then come back to the app - those functions are not called anymore.
this is only in IOS8 by the way

Comment: Yes but you still know the exact moments when it will be shown and when it will be closed (through the delegate). What's holding you back to call whatever was done in Disappear / Appear from those points in the code?

Comment: How do i know it? i thought i'd know it through "viewDidDisappear/Appear" - those are my hooking points which in IOS8 are not called..

Comment: Well you create the UIAlertController with actions. These actions will be called when you click one of the buttons. So the thing you need to do is to add a call to the other view controller (try to use a custom delegate so you don't end up with cross-includes) that will tell it the controller has been dismissed by a button click after you did what you wanted to do in your action.  https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:

Comment: Did you have any luck with that?

Comment: Hi, not yet, we had some work on other issues last days, i'll check this out tomorrow and let you know - i hope this will be helpful